# Issue an invoice

Tags: sentence-usage

Sometimes my customers ask me not to issue an invoice for the their purchase and I said “no”. Would the sentence below be correct answer for this situation?

> 1. I have to make the sales with the VAT invoice by law.

> 2. I have to sell these products with the VAT invoice by law.

Comment: Both are fine. Personally I prefer the second, and it's more natural to say *with **a** VAT invoice*, but these are stylistic choices. And there are any number of different phrasings with essentially the same meaning. But the people asking you not to issue an invoice are obviously trying to avoid paying tax on whatever you supply - if I were in your situation (well, I *was*, years ago), I'd use a few more words explaining to them the potential scale of the disaster it would be for *you* if the VatMan caught you fiddling your Vat returns (the most common reason UK startups fail, I believe).

Comment: Thank you so much. I wonder if this sentence means exactly I will sell products that have a vat invoice or I will sell products and I will issue a vat invoice for them.

Comment: "By law, I have to issue an invoice for VAT purposes when I make a sale."

Comment: Sorry I couldn’t understand. You mean my sentences means the same as your sentence

Comment: I think I would say "As I'm registered, I have to issue a VAT invoice, for all my sales".

Comment: Let's assume you're not trying to teach your tax-fiddling customers all the finer details of tax law. The basic message you're trying to get across is *you don't have a choice* (unless you want to break the law, which as I already said is a quick way to destroy your business). So basically the only part of your response that matters is ***No - by law** (I must collect the VAT; I can't help you avoid paying it).* All words apart from the first three are largely irrelevant.. (The customer will probably have stopped listening after the first word anyway! :)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: If the above comment was addressed to me, I was suggesting an idiomatic way to say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both seem fine grammatically, although they might not be the best and most idiomatic ways to express what you mean. They also may not be the most polite. While I don't want to stray into business advice that is off-topic for this site, the right legal stance will help you formulate what you want to say, so I'm going to talk a little about VAT.

It's fairly well-known in the UK that some people paying for *services* try to persuade tradesmen to not charge VAT by keeping the work 'off the books' and accepting cash as payment so there is no record of the transaction. In some cases it is the tradesman that initiates this, insisting on cash, so that they don't have to pay personal income tax on it, either. However, as a *retailer of goods*, you will be *paying* VAT on the goods you purchase, and then *charging* VAT when you resell them. If you are a VAT-registered business then you only have to submit the difference between what you collected and what you paid, which essentially means that, when all is accounted for, you don't pay VAT but your customers do. But you can't really avoid *charging* VAT on your sales and so there is no financial benefit to the customer whether they receive a paper invoice with their name on it, or not. I can only imagine that they fear their name on the invoice alone may fall under unwanted scrutiny by Customs and Excise.

I would think the politest way to express this is would be to ensure you refer only to *your* legal obligation, *not theirs*. Perhaps:

> I have to issue an invoice for my own VAT records.